# Graph isomorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that if $G = (V,E)$ and $G' = (V', E')$ are isomorphic graphs and $\phi: V \to V'$ is an isomorphism, then $d_G(x) = d_G'(\phi(x))$ for all $x \in V$. If, on the other hand, $\phi:V \to V'$ is a bijective mapping satisfying $d_G(x) = d_G'(\phi(x))$ for all $\phi:V \to V'$, then $G$ and $G'$ are not necessarily isomorphic.

I know that two undirected graphs $G = (V, E)$ and  $G' = (V', E')$ are isomorphic if there exists a bijective mapping $\phi: V \to V'$, such that $x, y \in V$ are adjacent if and only if $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ are adjacent. Though, I'm having hard time trying to prove the above statement.

Please note that $d(x)$ is the degree of vertex $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first half of the statement is not completely trivial to you, you do not understand graph isomorphisms yet. Look beyond the formal definition into what it *means*. If $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, they're really the same graph, just with their vertices and edges relabelled in some way - but all the connections remain the same. Of course the degree at every vertex remains the same before and after relabelling.

The second half is the non-trivial one. You need to draw two very similar undirected graphs, which you can match vertex by vertex with the same degree, but edges will *not* match no matter how you try to match the vertices. These cannot be very very simple graphs, you have to be a little sophisticated.

Hint: imagine a graph $V$ that is two chains of several vertices, a horizontal chain and a vertical chain, that meet in the middle in one vertex; a "cross" so to speak. In such a graph, the degrees will be $1$ at the $4$ ends of a cross, $4$ in the center vertex and $2$ everywhere else. Now try to draw a similar, but somewhat different "cross", which has the same number of vertices with the same degrees (so you can match them with a bijective function as required), but they really do not look like the same graph, they're genuinely *different*. Try to prove that they're not isomorphic.

Comment: The first part is clear to me that they are same graphs. Though, I'm having a bit hard time proving it mathematically.

Comment: $d_G(x)$ is the size of the set $\{y \in V: y \text{ adjacent to } x\}$. $d_G'(\phi(x))$ is the size of the set $\{y \in V': y \text{ adjacent to } \phi(x)\}$. But for every $y$ in $V$ that goes into the first set, $\phi(y)$ in $V'$ goes into the second set, and vice versa, by the definition of $\phi$. Because $\phi$ is also a bijection, it follows that the sets have the same sizes.

Comment: I still didn't manage to come up with such a prove. Can you show me the proof?

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that $d_G(x)=d_G'(ϕ(x))$ on isomorphic graphs, or for an example of non-isomorphic graphs with the same degrees (the second part of the question)?

Comment: For the first part, regarding the equal degrees, I used your previous comment, isn't it a sufficient proof? And for the second part, I need an example of non-isomorphic graphs with the same degree, and a bit more about how can it be proved from the examples.

Comment: Yes, I think it's sufficient proof (provided you actually understand it!). 

For non-isomorphic graphs with the same degrees: think of two intersecting chains of five vertices: 1-2-3-4-5 horizontal, and 6-7-3-8-9 vertical (draw them to see more easily). The second graph is 1-2-3-4-5 horizontal, and 6-7-4-8-9 vertical. Count the degrees of all vertices and find a bijection between $V$ and $V'$ that preserves degrees (this bijection will be idendity on most vertices but for example it will map 3 from the first graph to 4 in the second).

Comment: Now try to prove these two graphs are non-isomorphic. If there was an isomorphism $\phi$ between them, what could it look like? Certainly it has to preserve degree, so 3 has to map to 4 b/c these are the largest-degree vertices in both graphs. But in the second graph 4 is "closer to the edge" than 3 in the first. 4 in the second graph has a neighbour with degree 1, while 3 in the first doesn't have such a neighbour. Try to see how to formalize this observation into a more detailed proof of non-isomorphism.

Comment: I draw the graph, and it looks more or less like the coordinate system, with 3 in the middle. Now what would be a bijective function that will make the transformation you say? And how will I make it into a concrete mathematical proof? This doesn't help me much, I learn only when I see how the complete proof has been derived, like in the above comment with the first part of the question.

Comment: these are the two graphs: http://imgur.com/su7lMAB
with the nontrivial part of the bijection indicated (the rest all go identical 1->1, 2->2 etc.). You should verify that under this bijection $d_G(x) = d_G'(\phi(x))$ for all vertices $x$.

I will not write out the complete proof for you that the two graphs are non-isomorphic. As I said above, try to assume that there is some bijection $\phi$ that satisfies all requirements of an isomorphism, show that inevitably $\phi$ sends $3$ in the first graph to $4$ in the second, and try to see how to reach a contradiction looking at their neighbours.

Comment: We  consider both graph separate right? I mean degree of 3 at first graph is 2, and then in the send one 2 also. And when you say contradiction, you mean that in the first one, 7's neighbor is 3, but in the second one its neighbor is 4?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand degrees... a degree is just the number of neighbours. the degree of 3 in the first graph is 4, the largest in that graph, while 4 has degree 2. in the second graph, the vertex 4 has degree 4, while 3 has degree 2. this is why the bijection lines I drew swap around 3 and 4 between the two graphs, that's how they make it so the degree is preserved by the bijection.

Comment: what you say is a contradiction is not one. If $\phi$ is an isomorphism, and in the first graph 7's neighbour is 3, then what's required is that $\phi(7)$ is adjacent to $\phi(3)$ in the second graph. that's easy to arrange. \you need to understand why the graphs are different STRUCTURALLY. Suppose $\phi$ is some isomorphism. show why $\phi(3)$ is necessarily $4$ and not some other vertex in the second graph. Now in the first graph $3$'s neighbours are all degree-2 vertices, but in the second graph $4$ has a degree-1 neighbour $5$. That difference can be used to show a contradiction.